# Partial declarations must not specify different base classes

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf page named `StandardsDefault`. In the code behind,  `StandardsDefault`  is inheriting  `Page`, like all other pages.

```
<Page x:Class="namespace.StandardsDefault"

public partial class StandardsDefault : Page
```

Now I have created a new class `CountryStandards` which is inheriting `StandardsDefault` instead  of page.

```
<Page x:Class="namespace.CountryStandards"

public partial class CountryStandards : StandardsDefault
```

I have not  changed  the XAML . I am getting the error as

> "Partial declarations of `'CountryStandards'` must not specify different base classes"

I think the problem may be that the designer is not inheriting the same class.
But I need to somehow implement inheritance since there are many common methods which are to be used in many standard pages like `CountryStandards`

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: have you followed all the steps in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297433/how-do-you-specify-a-different-base-class-in-xaml-files-silverlight to set the base class of `CountryStandards` correctly?

Comment: After fixing the declaration with local:CountryStandards xmlns:local="using:..." in Visual Studio 2017, click Unload Project, Reload Project to get rid of this error in Error List.

Comment: All answers still not worth beeing 'accepted'?

Comment: @Eric response is the good answer for me

Answer (score 82):

You have to change your CountryStandards XAML to:

```
<src:StandardsDefault x:Class="namespace.CountryStandards" 
    xmlns:src="NamespaceOfStandardsDefault" ... />
```

There is a [good article](http://web.archive.org/web/20200221100003/http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2007/03/02/107747.aspx) about inheriting from a custom Window/Page in WPF.

Comment: good article link gives 404 :-(

Comment: @Gabriel I could not find a mirror of the post, here is a link to the wayback machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20200221100003/http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2007/03/02/107747.aspx

Answer (score 23):

Bit of an odd one, and it hasn't been listed here yet... But since none of the above answers applied because I had both my xaml and cs files declared correctly, I did the following and it seemed to work:

Go into the solution folder or click the show all files buton within Visual Studio and **delete both the obj and bin folders**, this causes Visual Studio to regenerate all of its files for the project.

Your project should now build/run correctly.

Hope that helps someone - or perhaps myself in the future.

Edit: This fix usually works if you get this problem after changing the page type from for example a ContentPage to a CarouselPage.

Comment: Ah ... the old 'delete the bin and obj folders' solution.  Works every time.  Will it solve Brexit as well??!?

Comment: It's a shame WPF needs to delete bin and obj folders so frequently while getting ghost errors...

Answer (score 5):

In your `CountryStandards.xaml` you should write

```
<StandardsDefault x:Class="namespace.CountryStandards"...
```

Answer (score 3):

For me : the partial codebehind class **must not** define any base class at all, even the same base class!

The error message is confusing.

WRONG:

```
xaml:
<someNamespace:SomeBaseClass x:Class="My.Namespace.ClassName" ...
```

C#:

```
namespace My.Namespace
{
    public partial class ClassName : SomeBaseClass 
    {
    }
}
```

RIGHT:

```
xaml:
<someNamespace:SomeBaseClass x:Class="My.Namespace.ClassName" ...
```

C#:

```
namespace My.Namespace
{
    public partial class ClassName
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Posting this just because I ran into a similar issue, albeit not the same, but maybe it will help somebody. I initially started with a UserControl, but then changed my control to inherit from Button. But, the XAML wasn't updated along side it automatically, so I forgot to change my XAML from UserControl to Button as well. It should be:

```
<Button x:Class="ThermostatGui.Shared.Controls.SetpointButton" .../>
```

not this

```
<UserControl x:Class="ThermostatGui.Shared.Controls.SetpointButton" .../>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure other partial classes are not extending a different class.

```
public partial class CountryStandards : StandardsDefault

public partial class CountryStandards : Page
```

You have to make them extends same class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use StandardsDefault as root node since you are creating a user control.since you are using page as root node c# compiler expects page as base. 
but in your you are using StandardsDefault as base so you need to use StandardsDefault as root node then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I did a complete cheat and used `dynamic`, probably breaks every rule in the book lol

```
        Assembly a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(); //get this app

        List<dynamic> l = new List<dynamic>(); //create a list

        // this list is our objects as string names
        // this if the full namespace and class, not just the class name 
        // I've actually stored these in my database so that I can control
        // ordering and show/hide from the database
        foreach(var app in listApplications) 
        {
            l.Add(a.CreateInstance(app)); //add them to my list
        }

        //as all my objects are the same this still works, you just don't get 
        //Intellisync which I don't care about because I know what I'm sending
        //all my objects are autonomous and self-contained and know nothing of any other objects
        //i have a main window/code that marshals the controls and data and manages view navigation
        l[0].DoThatFunction({ status ="new", message ="start", value = 0});
```

And then on the class

```
    public void DoThatFunction(dynamic data)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(data.message);//place-holder code but i'm sure you get the idea
    }
```

I like this because is oh so loosely coupled. As I'm porting an old app from Winforms to WPF this suits me as I can literally just copy and paste any code that's compatible. It might be the wrong thing to do but it works and will save me a ton of rework.

Also makes testing easy as I can 100% focus on each control in turn