# How to set Event Handler for element inside inherited Resource Dictionary in WPF Modern UI

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inheritance, modern-ui

I'm trying to overwrite some Modern UI templates. In this particular example I'm trying to put my own logo to ModernWindow with link to my web site. So, I added ModernWindow ResourceDictionary to my Themes folder like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:modernui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
                    xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:FirstFloor.ModernUI;assembly=FirstFloor.ModernUI">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/FirstFloor.ModernUI;component/Assets/Button.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/FirstFloor.ModernUI;component/Assets/Converters.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/FirstFloor.ModernUI;component/Assets/TextBlock.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyProject;component/Themes/MyModernMenu.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <Style TargetType="modernui:ModernWindow" x:Key="MyModernWindow">
    ...
        <!-- main menu -->
        <modernui:ModernMenu Grid.Column="1"
                             SelectedSource="{Binding Source, ElementName=ContentFrame, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             LinkGroups="{TemplateBinding MenuLinkGroups}" Style="{StaticResource MyModernMenu}"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Margin="-130,0,0,0">
                Powered by <Hyperlink x:Name="Link" NavigateUri="WWW.MyWebSite.com" RequestNavigate="Link_RequestNavigate">
                    <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Content/Images/MyLogo.png" Height="16" Width="55" Margin="0,0,0,-5"></Image>
            </Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
    ...
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then in my CodeBehind I have this class for this ResourceDictionary:

```
namespace MyProject.Themes
{
    class MyModernWindow : ModernWindow
    {
    }
}
```

This inherited from ModernWindow, which inherited from `ModernWindow : DpiAwareWindow`, which inherited from `DpiAwareWindow : Window`. So if I will just put x:class in my XAML like this:

```
x:Class="Elite3EDataExtractor.Themes.MyModernWindow"
```

Then I'm getting

```
Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'MyProject.Themes.MyModernWindow'; another partial declaration of this type exists
```

As I read in these questions:
[Is it possible to set code behind a resource dictionary in WPF for event handling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92100/is-it-possible-to-set-code-behind-a-resource-dictionary-in-wpf-for-event-handling)
and
[Partial declarations must not specify different base classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800872/partial-declarations-must-not-specify-different-base-classes)
I'm missing some rules for Window Inheritance. I'm kinda new in WPF, so please, can someone help me figure this out. What should I add/change in order to keep ModernUI ModernWindow functionality working and be able to add event handlers to `MyModernWindow.xaml.cs`. Please, let me know if I should put more code or explanation here.

Thanks